# Oracle PL/SQL function that accepts variable number of string parameters and returns comma separated

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need an Oracle PL/SQL function that accepts a variable number of string parameters and returns those strings comma separated with any null values ignored.

Can't find any examples on google.

So for example I would call:

```
foo('hello', null, 'world')
```

and it would return:

```
'hello, world'
```

or

```
foo('hello', 'world')
```

Comment: Is your data already stored in a table or are you passing in data from a client?

Comment: Just fixed list of parameters based on querying of per_addresses table. But there are different address styles and missing address lines.

Comment: If you're using 11gR2, you can use listagg()

Comment: LISTAGG() works across a column @Frank, not a row...

Comment: I know, but I understood that the OP has a list of values which you could then wrap in a PL/SQL table and use select listagg(column_value,...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment I'm assuming you have a row in a table, with some null columns, you now want  this to be a comma delimited string... There are *a lot* easier ways of doing this than a function. Given the following table:

```
create table the_table ( 
     a varchar2(100)
   , b varchar2(100)
   , c varchar2(100)
   , d varchar2(100)
      );

insert into the_table
values ('hello',null,'world', null);
```

You could do this, which comma delimits everything and then cleans up after itself.

```
select regexp_replace(trim(both ',' from a || ',' || b || ',' || c || ',' || d)
               , ',{2,}', ',')
  from the_table
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22776/5)

---

To provide a better explanation of TRIM() ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions219.htm#SQLRF06149)); the *default* behaviour of TRIM() is to remove trailing and leading whitespace, however, it can be used to remove any trailing and/or leading single character using the following syntax:

```
trim( <TRAILING|LEADING|BOTH trim_character FROM> trim_string )
```

where

- `TRAILING|LEADING|BOTH` indicates whether you want to remove trailing or leading characters, or both.
- `trim_character` is the character you want to remove
- `FROM` is syntactic sugar to make the entire thing make sense.

If an alternative character is specified then TRIM() does *not* remove trailing and leading whitespace.

For e.g. the following would both remove both trailing *and* leading semi-colons:

```
trim(both ';' from ';hello world;')
trim(';' from ';hello world;'
```

and this would remove leading hashes:

```
trim(leading '#' from '#hello world')
```

The documentation describes in more detail all the possible scenarios.

Comment: No idea why, but yeah that seems to work. Would still want to know how to do original function though.

Comment: What don't you understand @Superdooperhero, maybe I can explain it better? I just concatenate all the columns together with a comma, remove any leading or trailing commas and then if there's two together replace it with one... it's actually slightly wrong as it won't deal with `hello,,,world` so I've updated.

Comment: I've never seen the both and from bit.

Comment: Is there a way to add a space after the separating commas?

Comment: Yes, just add one in the concatenation: `a || ', ' || b...` @super

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about null values, but I would recommend to pass into function nested table:

```
create or replace TYPE "OT_VARCHAR_TABLE" as table of varchar2(200);

create or replace FUNCTION removeNulls(v_in_table OT_VARCHAR_TABLE) RETURN OT_VARCHAR_TABLE IS
....
```

In stored procedure code you can just filter values. This is simple to do.

**UPD.1**

Here is full code:

```
create or replace FUNCTION foo(v_in_table OT_VARCHAR_TABLE) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   vRes VARCHAR2(1000);
   BEGIN
    SELECT
      listagg(t.column_value,',') within group (order by t.column_value)
    INTO vRes
    FROM TABLE (CAST(v_in_table AS OT_VARCHAR_TABLE)) t;

    return vRes;
   END;
/
```

And usage:

```
select foo(OT_VARCHAR_TABLE('cc','aa', null, 'bb', null , null )) from sys.dual;
```

[Result](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abbb3/4/0):

```
aa,bb,cc
```

Comment: How do you iterate through the parameters passed in?

Comment: Updated answer. Don't think about iterations when you're dealing with PL/SQL

Comment: Thanks, but your code seems to assume that the values are all in column with multiple rows; whereas I have different address columns in one row; aka addr_line1, addr_line2, addr_line3, addr_line4

Comment: check the link in my post. It compiles properly via SQLFiddle. You can pass parameters as different columns too.
Select foo(OT_VARCHAR_TABLE(a.column1, a.column2, a.column3)) from T_MYTABLE a;